# Linear Change of Variables for Measurable Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I came across the following problem while studying measure theory from Tao's book; I feel like I am missing something but cannot figure out for the life of me how to prove it:

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to [0, + \infty]$ be a measurable function, with $T :\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ an invertible linear transformation. Show that
$$\int_{\mathcal{R}^d} f(T^{- 1}(x)) \, dx = |\det T| \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x) \, dx.$$

Any tips or suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: It would be helpful if you were more precise with your referencing. Which book precisely, and which problem? (This is good to do as sometimes people make mistakes when copying a question, or there are "ambient" assumptions in a section, and so the stated question is impossible and everyone gets frustrated!)

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you told is what you've tried. Are there related questions in the book with worked solutions, etc?

Comment: I was using "Introduction to Measure Theory" by Terence Tao. I actually figured this problem out by using the fact that $m(T(E)) = |\det T|m(E)$ and using the fact the lebesgue integral of a measurable function is the measure of the region under the graph.

Comment: Great! Would you consider writing it up here? Then the question will get an answer here, and also people can check your answer for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use Tao's book, I'll directly refer to the exercises in the text for this solution.

By Exercise $1.3.13$, it suffices to show that $m(A(f)) = |\det T|m(A(f \circ T))$, where $A(f)$ denote the region under the graph of $f$. By Exercise $1.2.21$, it then suffices to show that $A(f \circ T) = T'(A(f))$ for some linear transformation $T' :\mathbb{R}^{d+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ with $|\det T'| = |\det T|$.

Define $T' :\mathbb{R}^{d+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ by $T'(x, t) := (T^{-1}x, t)$, where $(x, t) \in \mathbb{R^d} \times \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R^{d+1}}$. We first show that $A(f \circ T) = T'(A(f))$. Let $(x, t) \in$ LHS. Then $x \in \mathbb{R^d}$ and $0 \leq t \leq f \circ T(x)$. Then $(x, t) = T'(Tx, t) \in$ RHS since $(Tx, t) \in A(f)$. On the other hand, if $T'(x, t) \in$ RHS, where $(x, t) \in A(f)$. Then $T'(x, t) = (T^{-1}x, t) \in$ LHS. Hence we have LHS = RHS.

Now we show that $|\det T'| = |\det T|$. This follows easily from linear algebra and our  definition of $T'$. For example, notice that the matrix $[T']$ associated with the transformation $T'$ is a $d + 1$ by $d + 1$ matrix formed by adding a unit row vector $e_{d+1} \in \mathbb{R^{d+1}}$ to the last row of the matrix $[T]$, and similarly adding a unit column vector $e^T_{d+1}$ to the last column of $[T]$. Then one can use the fact that for $B \in M_{n \times n}(F)$, $n \geq 2$， if row $i$ of $B$ equals $e_k$ for some $k(1 \leq k \leq n)$, then $|\det B|$ is the cofactor of the entry of $B$ in row $i$ column $k$.